# difference of property in interface and class

Tags: c#, oop

```
interface IVehicle
{
    int Id { get; set; }

    string Name { get; set; }

    void Print();          
}

class Car : IVehicle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Id {Id} Name {Name}");
    }
}
```

As we all know interface can only declare the members and we implement those members in classes which inherit from that interface.

So what is the difference then? Why do I have to re-declare the properties in the class? Can't it use the declarations from the interface?

Comment: I don't get what you're asking. You seem to understand the difference between an interface and a class. You *did* implement those properties in your class. As for creating them with values, you'd create an instance of a car and then assign values to the car's properties.

Comment: You implemented these properties, but didn't assign any value to them which is fine, because they will have a default value.

Comment: This code wont compile and the question is formed in a non understandable way.

Comment: @mason i aldreay know the difference b/w class and interface , and my ques is not that what you understand , i am asking that i define a property in class in a exact same way  as in interface , so what is the difference ?

Comment: @m.rogalski it compiled quite succesfully , you should read it again

Comment: An interface defines what a class *must* implement. That's the difference.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(//// );` does not compile successfully and is probably what m.rogalski is referring to.

Comment: @FCin dude you are the only one who got what i am trying to say (Y)

Comment: This, and many other questions, are answered by getting a nice beginner's book to c#.  You should do that.

Comment: @mason lol you got it wrong , it is just a example of implementation , thats not my actual implementation

Comment: @mason not only that but also this : `string name{ get; set; void print();`.

Comment: @faizan I got *what* wrong? I didn't say `Console.WriteLine(//// );` was your actual code. Just that you included it in your question and it wouldn't compile. Looks like that confused m.rogalski, understandably so.

Comment: @m.rogalski Good point, I didn't see that.

Comment: An interface defines a contract that classes implementing it *must* adhere to in order to compile. An interface does not say *how* the implementation must be done, only that it satisfies the interface. For example, you've created a string property for `name` that must expose a getter and setter. Your car uses autoproperties to satisfy the interface. However, you could have written your car like this: `private string _name; public string name { get { return _name;} set { _name = value; } }` and that would be perfectly valid since it still exposes a string property name with getters and setters.

Comment: @mason this is what exactly i was asking , thankyou (Y)

Comment: you just answered my both questions ..

Comment: @mason Interfaces can not contain any implementation (including default values) , this is what i understand ?

Comment: Correct. Classes can contain implementation. Abstract classes can contain implementation too (although they can't be be instantiated directly like a normal class)

Comment: @mason int Property { get; set; } inside a class, then it's an auto-property with implicit backing field and default value
int Property { get; set; } inside a interface, then it's not an auto-property with implicit backing field and without default value ?

Comment: In the interface, it's specifying the contract using auto property syntax, but interfaces do not describe implementation or default values, just the publicly visible part that a class must expose.

Comment: @mason this is what the confusing part in my  mind , thankyou so much for making it clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interface defines a contract that classes implementing it must adhere to in order to compile. An interface does not say how the implementation must be done, only that it satisfies the interface. For example, you've created a string property for Name that must expose a getter and setter.

Your Car implementation uses autoproperties to satisfy the interface. However, you could have written your car like this:

```
class Car : IVehicle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    private string _name;

    public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Id {Id} Name {Name}");
    }
}
```

and that would be perfectly valid since it still publicly exposes a string property Name with getters and setters.

When you first a create a car (`Car myCar = new Car();`, it will have default values for its properties. But you can modify those values:

```
IVehicle myCar = new Car();
myCar.Name = "The General";

//alternate syntax using object initializer
IVehicle schoolBus = new Car { Name = "Magic School Bus" };
```

Comment: int Id { get; set} (in IVehicles)
public int Id {get; set;} (in Car)
they both are different in meaning ?

Comment: @faizan Intefaces do not need to specify access modifiers. That's because an interface is describing the publicly accessible contract that a class must create. So putting `public` in the interface would be redundant, but the class that implements the interface must make everything described by the interface public.

Comment: ok i got it now thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you've defined that the properties must have a `get` and a `set` in the interface. Defining them the same way in the class creates an 'Auto-Property', which handles the implementationon your behalf, creating the backing variables, etc.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx for more reading on auto-properties if you want to dig into them further.